# Galería de imagenes, ¿Cómo puedo mostrar cada una de ellas en el lightbox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy creando una galería de imagenes con bootstrap y cuando clico en una de las imagenes con clase "card-img-top" se abre el lightbox con una imagen. ¿Cómo hago que el src de la imagen que hay en el ligthbox sea el de la imagen que estoy clicando? Este es el script que he creado:

```
 <script>
        $('#lightbox').hide();
        $('img.card-img-top').click(function(){
            $('#lightbox').show('slow');
            $('#imagenlightbox').attr("src","AQUI QUIERO LA IMAGEN QUE HE CLICADO);
        });

        $('#cerrar').click(function(){
            $('#lightbox').hide('slow');
        });

    </script>
```

¡¡Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: debes colocar tu codigo html tambien... una opcion `.attr("src",$(this).attr("src"))`

Comment: ¡¡Gracias!! Era justo lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 1):

Seria asi:

```
$('body').on('click' , 'img.card-img-top', function() {

/*  ...  */

  // Obtiene el valor src del objeto this de esta imagen que se le dio click
  let this_src_image = $(this).attr('src');

  // annadir al #imagenlightbox el src de la imagen que se dio click
  $('#imagenlightbox').attr("src" , this_src_image);

/*  ...  */

});
```